# Как выровнять текст по картинке

Tags: html, css

есть код

```
<a href="ya.ru">
    <h3 class="user_name"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/***.jpg">Имя Фамилия</h3>
</a>
```

И стили к нему

```
.user_name{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Хотелось бы примерно так, подскажите как сделать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте задавать vertical-align: middle для изображения

```
.user_name img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Вы не задали стиль.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант использовать display: flex; Свойство align-items: center выровняет элементы по поперечной оси.

```
<a href="ya.ru">
        <h3 class="user_name">
            <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c636822/v636822048/538d4/mHGjveJFopU.jpg">
            Имя Фамилия
        </h3>
    </a>
```

Css код:   .user_name {display:flex; align-items: center;}

Comment: Должно работать. http://jsbin.com/rokiduc/edit?html,css,output

Comment: flex избыточен в данном случае